# Accordion toggle redirecting before jquery load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have the following code causing issue on a website.
Basically, if a user has a slow internet speed and manages to click the accordion before bootstrap js is loaded, it redirects to the homepage with #i at the end.

I've added this at the end:

```
  $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

But of course some users can still click the a tag before this is loaded. Any help would be great.

```
 <div class="panel-heading">
     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $x; ?>">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>


<div id="<?php echo $x; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
</div>
<div id="<?php echo $x; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
</div>
```

Comment: make a script that only shows the body after all other scripts are loaded. It should come after bootstrap.js  onload(boodstrap.js){showbody}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the archor in href, put only **#**

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $x; ?>">
                                        </a>
```

to:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="<php for target>" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
      <div class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" role="button">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
      </div>
      </h5>
</div>
```

Use a DIV instead of the button, after that add the **role="button"** attribute in the DIV and it will work